# Changing starting place for arrow in XY picture

Tags: xymatrix

This script

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\xymatrix @R=0.3pc @C=0.3pc{ 
     & N_0\oplus G_1 & N_1\oplus G_2 \ar@/_1.5pc/[l]_u }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

give the following result
[image]

I wish that the arrow start from the "G_2" and arrive in "G_1".
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE. Could you make your script in the to form of a MWE?

Comment: Is a `tikz-cd` solution acceptable to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document} 
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
N_0\oplus G_1 
& N_1\oplus G_2 
\arrow[l, bend right=60, "u", swap, start anchor={[xshift=-10pt]north east}, end anchor={[xshift=-10pt]north east}]\\
\end{tikzcd}
\] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want an arrow tip like `xymatrix` add

```
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>={Straight Barb[length=5pt,width=5pt]}}}
```

in your preamble, after `\usepackage{tikz-cd}`, and you'll get:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tikz` package. Please consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
N_0\oplus \tikz[baseline]{\node[fill=blue!20,circle,inner sep=1pt,anchor=base] (t1){$G_1$}} \quad 
N_1\oplus \tikz[baseline]{\node[fill=red!20,circle,inner sep=1pt,anchor=base] (t2){$G_1$}}
\end{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\draw[-latex](t2.90)to[in=60,out=120]node[midway,above]{$u$}(t1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

**Note:** You can easily change or remove nodes color.

```
\begin{equation}
N_0\oplus \tikz[baseline]{\node[fill=none,draw=none,inner sep=1pt,anchor=base] (t1){$G_1$}} \quad 
N_1\oplus \tikz[baseline]{\node[fill=none,draw=none,inner sep=1pt,anchor=base] (t2){$G_1$}}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

You could also change the output and input angle and position of arrow, by changing the following line in the code:

```
\draw[-latex]($(t2)+(-1mm,2mm)$)to[in=60,out=120]node[midway,above]{$u$}($(t1)+(-1mm,2mm)$);
```

[image]

Comment: Please add `anchor=base` to each node.

Comment: I edit my response, please try again.